# Is Jesus from the line of David?

Tags: matthew, jesus, david, messiah

I have been reading the New Testament in more depth for the last 3 years and am seeing a lot of discrepancies in the texts. I am feeling a bit deceived that all these years I have been told lies. Hoping my questions will get thoughtful and truthful answers from believers who can help me overcome these doubts I have been having about Christianity. Hope this forum can help restore my faith.

**Verse**
**Matthew 1:16**

> and Jacob the father of Joseph, the husband of Mary, and Mary was the
> mother of Jesus who is called the Messiah.

**Issues I see**
•   Since Jesus was born of the Holy Spirit and not Joseph is Jesus from the line of David?
•   God was clear with Abraham about Isaac that a mighty nation will emerge from him.
•   God was clear that David’s throne through Solomon will rule Israel for ever.
•   The biological father decides which tribe the son belongs to.
•   Technically this would be genealogy of Joseph not Jesus?

**What Christian Pastors Teach**
•   Jesus was adopted by Joseph.
•   Joseph was the earthly father of Jesus

Comment: Hi Yeddu Prasad, welcome! A bit sad to see your faith is being this shaked by something you're not understanding / seeing at the moment (as in relying on your own limited understanding - Proverbs 3:5-6)... Allow me to share a link to that [same question but in a different community](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56826/42957) in hopes that helps calming the storms going in your heart.

Comment: Dear Tiago, Thank you for your reply and I have read every message in the discussion group. No lineage is done through the mother. Nothing there seems right.

Yes, I have believed in Christianity for 48 years. Always beleived that Jesus is the Son of God and there is no salvation except through his blood. 

For the last 3 years, I have been reading the New Testament and Tanak and have found over 100 issues so far in just the 3 gospels. 

How can so many issues be there and all I can see around me is people going through agonizing pains to right things

Truth is simple & not complicated

Comment: @YedduPrasad What about Luke's geneology through Mary/Miriam? Also, I would say that truth is nearly always complicated, as the world is complicated. Whole books are made to describe truths about love, racism, history, etc. If it was all so simple, why would God's Word need to be longer than most of those books?

Comment: The Father always decides the tribe. Mother decides if a person is a jew(Israelite) or not.

Truth is always simple...We just make it complicated. 

Also when we start a lie and are stubborn not to accept that we lied, all we are left with is a whole lot of theories, suppositions, fallacies, theories, assumptions, doctrines. 

We finally come to a stage when we look back and wonder what is the truth. Was it all worth it

I somehow believe that my life has been so blessed since I started being bold to speak the truth even if meant punishment, loss... 

God Bless

Comment: With regard to your 100 'issues' I have studied the scripture for over fifty years now and I have never found, myself, or heard of anyone else finding, an 'issue' that was not fully resolvable by proper examination. Every single time, it is 'user' error, I have found.

Comment: God bless you Nigel. I will share my questions with you. Please try to help me as I am sincerely seeking the truth, not interpretations, theories, doctrines. Can you share your email id with me. Mine is yeddu.prasad@outlook.com

Comment: @YedduPrasad might as well ask the questions here if they follow community standards (you'd get more attention). It'll be handy if you read first [this Meta post](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3770/27054) to understand how to better proceed when one has a list of questions. For reference I have such list too with over 140 atm questions just for 1 Samuel to Neemias (when stopped asking questions here temporarily due to not having the time to be searching + asking) ... God willing it'll come the time to ask the ones that are not yet existing here.

Comment: Joseph, as you have already ascertained, was of the line of David but, indeed, he did not do the impregnating. This used to fool me, just like it has you, until I found out that Mary was also of the line of David. Mary was of the tribe of Judah. Jesus "...was born of a descendant of David according to the flesh..." Ro, 1:3 NASB. Jesus not only had a legal right, through his adoptive father Joseph but the hereditary right also through Mary, as the 'offspring,' 'seed,' and 'root' of David.

Comment: Mary(Mother) does not decide the tribe of her child. Luke attempts to fix the issue by tracing the line of Mary.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be well researched regarding this issue. And there is a plethora of content online expounding every angle, every viewpoint. I doubt you’ll come across something ‘new’ on this forum - more likely a rehash of what you’ve already encountered - and put aside?

Nevertheless- Let’s highlight some points for consideration. You say “*The biological father decides which tribe the son belongs to.*”. This isn’t so in Jewish tradition. Although it’s difficult to show why the Rabbis use the maternal line, nevertheless they do. So Miriam’s genealogy is the determining factor in tribal affiliation.

You need to remember that the eligibility of Jesus for being entitled to the throne is a question for the Jews to settle. Not ‘us westerners’. Let’s look at some criteria they expect. Remember that due to the historical split, there are two distinct branches for this nation. Judah, (and Benjamin), and Israel (Northern 10 tribes).

The requirements for sitting on the throne for Judah was Davidic descendancy. No one was allowed to sit on David's throne unless he was a member of the house of David. Now the ‘key point’ here is *house* of David. Not bloodline.

This is crucial - because there was a curse put onto Davids bloodline. From Jeconiah. (Jeremiah 22 24-30). So Jesus **couldn’t** be a ‘blood’ descendant of David! That’s why Jesus couldn’t have a ‘blood’ connection to Joseph. But nevertheless had a connection to David through Joseph, as Joseph was ‘legally’ [in Jewish/Mosaic law] Jesus’s father.

So Jesus had a ‘legally accepted’ connection to the *house* of David through both Joseph, and Mary - and also was *not* ‘under’ the curse God pronounced on Jeconiah.

Now for the Northern house of Israel - to be King here, came by prophetic sanction or divine appointment. So ‘technically’ Jesus had to be eligible under two sets of requirements.

So, why or how could Jesus claim the throne of David? He was a member of the house of David apart from Jeconiah. And, He alone received divine appointment to that throne: (“The Lord God will give him the throne of his father David.")

These points are for consideration. Both you and I are aware the online world abounds with experts who refute/support various interpretations regarding this issue. But here is the ‘bottom line’. The Jewish community is saturated with experts in the Old Testament. Rabbinic scholars. Absolute masters in Mosaic and Prophetical legalism. They are the ones that need to be, ( and arguably are.) satisfied with the eligibility of Jesus to the throne of David. Because the Bible is a Jewish book.

(Reference: The Genealogy of the Messiah" by Dr Arnold G. Fruchtenbaum)

Comment: The Mother decides if a person is a Jew or not Not. The father decides which tribe the person belongs to. Please refer to the whole book of Numbers. It is always the father that decides the tribe. Also, if you recollect the story about the daughters of Zelophehad(numbers 27:1)  same issue.
I agree that this is an issue for the Jews to place Jesus from a lineage point of view, but according to the New Testament, the same messiah/christ decides who goes to hell and who goes to heaven. If you don't tie the new testament to Tanak it is all good. Just not able to take the lies anymore.

Comment: Please refer to Haggai 2:23. God restores the Jeconiah curse. But since you brought up the adoption part, there is no text that an adopted son becomes a legal heir. That said, I see no need for the adoption theory other than to link it with the Tanak. Why not just believe in what the New Testament says and just not link it with the Tanak.
1. Jesus is Son of God
2. Jesus is God
3. Jesus stating that David praised him and hence he is superiour to David
4. Pauls statement that he has fulfilled to be born of Flesh

Comment: Are you referring to 2 Samuel 7:12 when you say (“The Lord God will give him the throne of his father David.")? I believe this is referring to Solomon. In verse 13 it says he will build God a temple.

Comment: Agreed and up-voted save for one point. Mary was a close relative of Elziabeth who was 'of the daughters of Aaron'. Thus the only way that this could be possible is by Mary, also, being of Levi. Which, by the way, fulfils the prophecies (in Jesus) regarding Phinehas.

Comment: @Yeddu Prasad As I said, you seem well researched. As I said, I doubted you’d find something new. I provided this outline for consideration, so thanks for doing that. Couple of things, the Tanakh **is** the source that *must* be used for this, and using it can/does reflect eligibility - Second - you said ...”*the same messiah/christ decides who goes to hell and who goes to heaven*” - it’s not his decision that decides where you go. All the best in your pursuit for answers, I’m sure you’ll find what you want.

Comment: @Yeddu Prasad One further point - If you haven’t already referenced it, I refer you to the comment by Nigel J regarding tribal connection.

Comment: Dave, Christianity says that if you don't believe in Jesus is god you will go to hell. On the other hand, Tanakh says there is only one God and no trinity. That is the reason I am doing this study, not for any intellectual drive

Answer (score 3):

**Direct Evidence**
There are two explicit witnesses which state Jesus was of the line of David:

> The book of the genealogy of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham
> (Matthew 1:1 ESV)

> Jesus, when he began his ministry, was about thirty years of age, being the son (as was supposed) of Joseph, the son of Heli...the son of Melea, the son of Menna, the son of Mattatha, the son of Nathan, the son of David... (Luke 3:23, 31)

Matthew, who gives the birth account from Joseph's perspective, begins by stating Jesus was the Christ and son of David and Abraham. (Note: Christ is the Greek title given to the Messiah who was to be a Davidic ruler. The title alone is sufficient evidence of ancestry.) Luke, who gives the account from Mary's perspective, traces Jesus' genealogy back to Adam through David and Abraham. Both understood Jesus to be a son of David.

Additionally, Luke points to another consideration: Mary's lineage could also connect with David's (cf. [Romans 1:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201%3A3&version=ESV)). In that case, Jesus would be a descendant of David biologically through Mary and by adoption through Joseph.<sup>`1`</sup>

John, like Mark, does not give a specific genealogy, but he does give two witnesses which confirm the Jewish people considered Jesus to be Joseph's son:

> Philip found Nathanael and said to him, “We have found him of whom Moses in the Law and also the prophets wrote, Jesus of Nazareth, the son of Joseph.” (1:45)

> They said, “Is not this Jesus, the son of Joseph, whose father and mother we know? How does he now say, ‘I have come down from heaven’ ?” (6:42)

John also includes compelling evidence Jesus' genealogy to David was not disputed:

> <sup>30</sup> Now Jesus did many other signs in the presence of the disciples, which are not written in this book; <sup>31</sup> but these are written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name. (John 20)

John provided other evidence Jesus was the Christ because not only was Jesus' ancestry was not in question, ancestry by itself was not the deciding factor.

**Virgin Birth & Maternal Priority**
It appears the OP rejects what Scripture states and what the Jewish people of the period accepted on the basis of the virgin birth.<sup>`2`</sup>Therefore, since Joseph was not the biological father, the claim to be a descendent of David is invalid. In addition to those Scriptures which state otherwise, there are several reasons why line of reasoning can be rejected.

The virgin birth is a unique event. As such the normal rules governing ancestry cannot be assumed to apply. Rather, just as Moses went to the LORD with a situation involving the daughters of Zelophehad, it will be
the LORD's records which will decide the question:

> <sup>5</sup> And of Zion it shall be said,
> “This one and that one were born in her”;
> for the Most High himself will establish her. <sup>6</sup> The LORD records as he registers the peoples,
> “This one was born there.” (Psalm 87)

This Old Testament passage shows the LORD not only maintains the register of births; He determines heritage.

Moreover, if this is the objection, it is unreasonable to deny the ancestry Scripture states on the basis of a miraculous conception, which was necessary to fulfill Scripture.

Additionally, the chosen people are biologically differentiated from those not chosen solely on the basis of a woman. The DNA which separates Abraham's descendants is from the mother. It is Sarah's DNA which separates Isaac from Ishmael, Zimran, Jokshan, Medan, Midian, Ishbak, and Shuah. This shows paternal relationship is not the determining factor. DNA testing, which is used to prove  paternity, points to another consideration. If God can bring a virgin birth, He can do so with DNA identical to any of David's sons, or even David himself (cf. [Psalm 139:13; Isaiah 44:2, 24, 49:5; Jeremiah 1:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20139%3A13%3B%20Isaiah%2044%3A2%2C%2024%2C%2049%3A5%3B%20Jeremiah%201%3A5&version=ESV))

The Law also provides for a man's name to be continued even if he does not father a child:

> <sup>5</sup> “If brothers dwell together, and one of them dies and has no son, the wife of the dead man shall not be married outside the family to a stranger. Her husband's brother shall go in to her and take her as his wife and perform the duty of a husband's brother to her. <sup>6</sup> And the first son whom she bears shall succeed to the name of his dead brother, that his name may not be blotted out of Israel. (Deuteronomy 25)

The Law considers a child who has no biological connection to the deceased husband, to be his son. As with Sarah, what determines ancestry is the woman. In such cases, there is neither a biological connection nor a formal adoption by the husband. Nevertheless, solely on the basis of marriage, the son is considered a descendent of the husband.

If the Law decrees a son born through such a relationship to be the son of a man who had no biological part in the conception of the child, then a son born through a virgin could reasonably be considered in the same light.

---

<sub>1. The issue of ancestry cannot be dismissed solely on the basis of adoption. For example, Jacob claimed Manasseh and Ephraim as his own sons and through them Israel would be named *...and in them let my name be carried on, and the name of my fathers Abraham and Isaac; and let them grow into a multitude in the midst of the earth.”* (Genesis 48:16) and *“By you Israel will pronounce blessings, saying, ‘God make you as Ephraim and as Manasseh.’”* (Genesis 48:20) Clearly Jacob believed the adopted sons were no different than those born to him.</sub>
<sub>2. The Greek translation of Isaiah reads, *Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. Look, the virgin shall be with child and bear a son, and you shall name him Emmanouel.* As this was done 200 years before the birth of Christ, it reflects a pre-Christian understanding of the prophecy, which is also found in the Gospels.</sub>

Comment: 1. Just because Matthew & Luke said that Jesus was the Son of David does not make him the Son of David. The same writers said that Jesus was born to Mary through the spirit and no human male was involved.

2. In the time of Jesus, everyone believed that Joseph and Mary were a normal married couple and had children and the first son born to them was Jesus.

3. Like you and I read the bible today, in Jesus' time(0000-0030 BCE) there was no documentation of Jesus. Mark was written in 65-70 BCE and all the others followed. Till Then all was the word of mouth

Comment: I agree that every descendent of David is NOT christ and the Christ has to be a descendent of David.

I am asking help to show that Jesus is the decedent of David. I have no doubts that Jesus is christ as told by the new testament.

The issue I am seeing if you tie it back to the Tanak.

Comment: The Jews in Jesus' time did not believe that Jesus was born to a virgin. Bible says Joseph did not reject mary meaning he hid the fact that he is not the father. Had Joseph sent her away, she would have been stoned to death for adultary. The Jews of Jesus' time believed Jesus was born to Mother Mary + Father Joseph. The + means the natural human way.

Comment: There are multiple issues in your next statement about the daughters of Zelophehad. This is a story that exactly makes my point that the father decides the tribe. Please read Numbers 36:5-9 it is very clear.

Comment: Next you talk about a virgin birth being prophesied,  Probably the verse you are referring to Isaiah 7:14. The word in Tanak is Young Woman Christian bible changed it to Virgin to match with the virgin birth in Matthew. The tense has been changed from past tense to future tense. The use of the word THE refers to a specific woman that Ahaz knows about. The verse in Isaiah 7 Is during the 4th year of Ahaz and is referring to Hezekiah Verse 16 talks about how the 2 kings Aram and Pekah will be destroyed before the child matures. This is what happened during the lifetime of Hezekiah

Comment: Virgin births are not common either in Jewish or Christian beliefs. Please see how this is such a common Greco-Roman belief. Almost all their huge heroes are born when a god impregnates a virgin and once these people die they become demi-gods.

Comment: God promised Abraham that a son will be born to Him and Sarah and his name was to be Isaac. Ishmael was never the promise. (Genesis 19:17)
Same between Absolam and Solomon. God Promised that there will a King forever on David & Solomons's throne(1 Kings 1:17, 2 Samuel 7:11-13) so why do see a need for help from the mother in either of these two cases?

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand your Point 3 about a Levirate son. it has no relevance to Jesus and the virgin birth and most importantly Joseph is right there....

Answer (score 1):

These are the Biblical facts:

1. Jesus is regularly called the "Son of David" in places such as Matt 1:1, 9:27, 15:22, 20:30, 31, 21:15, Mark 10:47, 48, 12:35, Luke 18:38, 39, etc.
2. Jesus' earthly father, Joseph, is also called, the "Son of David" by the angel in Matt 1:20.
3. While Jesus was clearly conceived by the Holy Spirit as per Luke 1:35 and Matt 1:18, 19, (ie, and not by Joseph) this did not prevent Jesus being "regarded as the son of Joseph" as per Luke 3:23.
4. Matthew's genealogy is placed at the beginning of his gospel to demonstrate that Jesus Christ was the fulfilment of the OT prophecies about Messiah, and specifically, being the "Son of David".
5. When Nathaniel was introduced to Jesus, he exclaimed (John 1:49), “Rabbi,” Nathanael answered, “You are the Son of God! You are the King of Israel!”  Such a remark could only be true if Jesus was the Son of David and thus, heir to the Davidic throne, as Jesus was.
6. God promised there would always be a blood descendant of David on his throne, by an eternal “covenant of salt” (ie very solemn), 2 Chron 13:5, forever, 2 Sam 7:13, 15, 16, Eze 37:26, (2 Sam 23:5).  In the NT, Jesus is described specifically as fulfilling these promises. Acts 13:32-37, Heb 1:8.  Note especially, what the angel said to Mary before Jesus’ birth in Luke 1:32, 33 –

> He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. The Lord
> God will give Him the throne of His father David, and He will reign
> over the house of Jacob forever. His kingdom will never end!”

7. Finally, the triumphal entry to Jerusalem recorded in Matt 21:1-11 could only be possible if Jesus was indeed the Son of David and heir to the Davidic throne.  The triumphal entry ceremony was the usual practice of ancient kings which Jesus was enacting.

Comment: @YedduPrasad - you have misunderstood point #5 - Jesus is declared the king of Israel - which is only possible if He is the Son of David.

Comment: Not sure how I should respond in this forum to answers I get so here goes.,...

Thanks for your inputs, I am looking for more insightful and truth-based answers.All you statements have issues.
1. Just because people called Jesus Son of David does not make him the son of David. He must be born to a father who is from the line of David.
2. Joseph indeed is the son of David as per the lineages quoted in the New Testament.
3. Just because Luke says it does not make him the Son of David

Comment: 4. Matthew is not the first Gospel chronologically not sure why it comes first. Common sense tells that when you are going to talk about Jesus, you start with where he came from. Just because he placed it, in the beginning, does not prove he is teh son of David.
5. Don't see any basis for your conclusion. Because Nathanel called Jesus the Son of God he is also the Son of David
6. You said it correctly. The Messiah should be a physical descendent of David not a Son of God.

Comment: 7. In ancient times a priest whould anoint the king and the people will bring him into the kingdom. Here not even his disciples brought Jesus in as a king. Jesus asked for a colt himself and came into the city. Also just becuase someone comes into the city with a following does not make him a king in the line of David.

Comment: Dear Dottard, Not sure how to respond to your comment you just sent, but Here goes.

Just because a crowd welcomed him, does not make him the king. A King comes in and takes the throne and rules.
The prophecy of what needs to happen when the messiah comes has not happened.
I don't mean to offend anyone, but I am seeking the truth & none of what you said answers the question of how Jesus can be from David's line.

I am absolutely in agreement that Jesus is the son of God and he will take away our sins if we say he is lord and that God sent him.
All this fails when you link it with Tanak

Comment: Dottard, Also nowhere Jesus claimed he is the King of Israel. He in fact said, his Kingdom is not of this world.

Comment: @YedduPrasad - You appear to have very strong opinions and not really seeking others views here.  Why not present your own answer.

Comment: Dottard, Sorry if I offended you or came out strong. I am interested in the truth that God said. I don't care to have an opinion, I am just seeking the truth.

Comment: @YedduPrasad - I am not offended - no apology necessary.  People here present their views and understandings - respect them even if you disagree.  Why ask for opinions and then criticise the opinions?

Comment: Dottard, If this forum is about someone's point of view,  I am in the wrong place. Will exit immediately. I need to know what God said, not what people think. God bless

Comment: @YedduPrasad - if you are seeking direct divine information, then I know of so site that will do that apart from the Bible itself which we are here to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

It is a virtual mathematical certainty that Jesus was a biological descendent of David. Let's consider the genealogist's dilemma.

**The Math**

- Go back one generation--your parents--you have 2^1 (2 to the first
  power) of them
- Go back 10 generations--your 8th great-grandparents--you have 2^10 of
  them
- Go back 20 generations--your 18th great-grandparents--you have 2^20
  of them (just over a million)

David lived about a millennium before Jesus. If we allow for 25 years to a generation (not unreasonable for the time period), that's 40 generations. 40 generations back are your 38th great-grandparents and you have 2^40 of them. The trouble is, 2^40 is more than 1 trillion--and it's more than the total number of people who have ever lived on the earth.

--

1 trillion ancestors--how does that work?? It turns out if you go back far enough on your family tree you'll see the same names showing up on different branches. Your parents may not be closely related, but they are related--they have common ancestors. Those trillion names on the 40th generation branches of the family tree will be repeats of the same names over and over and over and over again.

This is why genealogists believe, for example, that everyone of western European descent is a descendant of Charlemagne. Not only did he have a lot of kids, but he lived almost 1300 years ago--the number of his descendants has multiplied exponentially, such that there came a point where even the handful of people who weren't his descendants would have an awful hard time finding someone to marry (in Europe) who wasn't a descendant of Charlemagne! I am a descendant of Charlemagne (too bad I didn't inherit his fortune though).

People who share a common regional ancestry are all related within 40 generations--and in a community like the Israelites, who tended to intermarry (see Deut. 7:3-4), it would take a lot less than 40 generations.

So yes, Jesus was a biological descendant of David. And so was every other Jew in Galilee.

--

**Aside to guard against counter-arguments**

It appears the math I've cited has caused some confusion--I'll briefly elaborate. I use 2^40 to make a point, but:

- The argument will work just fine if we use 2^39 instead (just over 500 billion), since Jesus had only 1 mortal parent.
- The argument will still work even if we use the condensed genealogy from Matthew, listing only 27 generations from David to Jesus: 2^27 is ~134.2 million. (I'm not suggesting Matthew's genealogy doesn't skip generations, just pointing out that using Matthew's genealogy as a counter-argument won't work)
- The argument works yet again if we combine both objections above, using 27 generations from Matthew *and* subtracting 1 from the exponent because Jesus had only 1 mortal parent: 2^26 is ~67.1 million, more than the total population of Jews in the Roman Empire in Jesus' time.
- Some have suggested a 25-year average generation is too high--that we should use a smaller number because of shorter lifespans. That's fine, it would only strengthen my argument by increasing the exponent.

--

**Jesus' more precise claims**

So what was significant about Jesus' claims of David descent? At least 2 things:

1. He could *actually trace His genealogy* back to David. For comparison, everybody on earth is descended from royalty somewhere, but most can't trace their lineage back that far.
2. He had legal, patrilineal claim as an heir of David. As a patrilineal descendant of David, Joseph had a plausible claim on the throne (though admittedly, not entirely without difficulty). As Joseph's adopted son, Jesus had a plausible claim as well (see discussion [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/new-testament-studies/article/abs/jesus-davidic-lineage-and-the-case-for-jewish-adoption/92B32A053628FD94923EA24871CCBC2C)). This is why, for example, several of Joseph's descendants were investigated by Emperor Domitian in case they posed a threat of claiming right to rule and thereby threatening Rome's rule over the Jews (see Eusebius, HE 3.19 & 3.20).

As noted in the comments, this means Jesus' brothers could also have claimed to be the Messiah...but the records suggest none of them ever did. Being a descendant of David did not automatically make one the Messiah--it was a necessary but not a sufficient condition.

--

**Aside on adoption**

Was Joseph Jesus' adopted father? Yes

From his own community we get the following:

> And all bare him witness, and wondered at the gracious words which
> proceeded out of his mouth. And they said, Is not this Joseph’s son?
> (Luke 4:22)

And from Mary herself, after she & Joseph found Jesus (at age 12) in the temple:

> thy father and I have sought thee sorrowing. (Luke 2:48)

What Matthew & Luke make clear is that Joseph was *not Jesus' biological father*.

--

**The power of hostile witness**

As you've noted, how do we actually know the claim of traceable Davidic descent is true? One of the criteria used to establish historical credibility is the testimony of hostile witnesses. If Jesus' enemies conceded something, that means it was pretty much incontrovertible.

The Gospels record multiple run-ins Jesus had with the religious leaders of His time, and they challenged Him on many points. His trial before the Sanhedrin is multiply attested in detail. And yet amidst their numerous challenges of Jesus' claims, person, and teachings, *never* do we find anyone challenging His well-known claim to be a descendant of David.

Some have suggested Jesus never claimed to be the Messiah--He does in Matthew 27:64:

> 63 But Jesus held his peace. And the high priest answered and said
> unto him, I adjure thee by the living God, that thou tell us whether
> thou be *the Christ*, the Son of God.
>
> 64 Jesus saith unto him, Thou hast said: nevertheless I say unto you,
> Hereafter shall ye see the Son of man sitting on the right hand of
> power, and coming in the clouds of heaven. (Matthew 27:63-64)

- Note that "Christ" is the Greek equivalent of "Messiah"
- The Greek idiom behind "thou hast said" here has often been garbled
  in translation. The Greek is Σὺ εἶπας. As explained by Talmage:

> This expression "Thou has said" was equivalent to -- I am what thou
> hast said. (Jesus the Christ pp. 625-626)

--

**The Synoptic Problem and the Genealogies**

You noted in a comment that Matthew was not the first Gospel written. I respectfully hold a different view. My study of the Synoptic Problem has led me to the conclusion that both Mark and Luke were dependent upon Matthew. For a much more extended argument (if that's of interest), see my work on Matthean Priority [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5i8CVQcNzf4pBIA8hC-AIpN) and the reliability of the Gospels [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5iFeKqqvQPK_dzMnjF7NBhw). (Matthean Priority = Matthew was first)

I recognize that most scholars believe in Markan Priority; I also recognize why they do so. For a brief discussion, see [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/54190/39862) under the heading *It’s the majority view among New Testament scholars: this is unremarkable given the history of the Synoptic Problem*; for a more extensive discussion, see  my videos [here](https://youtu.be/ZDGChDOnQxE) and [here](https://youtu.be/MqH822XBPU0).

But this also creates a conundrum. If Luke used Matthew as a source--and I firmly conclude he did--why are the genealogies different?

As demonstrated on this site and many others, a definite answer on the differing genealogies is not universally acknowledged. But if Luke knew Matthew's Gospel and used a different genealogy anyway, that means one of two things:

- Luke thought Matthew was wrong (unlikely since he quoted hundreds of verses from Matthew)
- Luke had access to a different family line

I don't claim to know the answer for certain, but to me the most parsimonious solution is that one evangelist recorded Joseph's genealogy and one recorded Mary's.

--

**Conclusion**

That Jesus was a descendant of David we can establish on the math alone. That His genealogy could be traced to David is supported by hostile witness, and that His family could credibly claim patrilineal descent from David is attested by the fact that Emperor Domitian--politically the most powerful man in the world at his time--went to the trouble to track the poor family down.

---

Addendum--a personal note

(I'll move this to chat if the moderators don't approve of my having included this)

Hi Yeddu Prasad, welcome to the site, and thanks for sharing your thoughts. We all experience faith and doubt. To paraphrase Shayne Bowen: which one wins? *The one that we feed.*

If you are interested, there are two links I'll share.

1. A sermon I love by Dieter Uchtdorf: [Doubt your doubts before you doubt your faith](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2013/10/come-join-with-us?lang=eng)
2. My own epistemological journey, which has led me (much to the chagrin of some on this site) not to be bothered by potential discrepancies in the Bible, is described [here](https://youtu.be/E1jiTecD9K0).

Comment: I am looking for is a simple truth that Jesus born to a descendent of David. A married B and they had a son C called Jesus. Is not the whole bible full of such statements? Why is Jesus' Geneology so difficult?

1. Your math approach has issues as 27 is not the right number of generations from David to Jesus(1 chr 3). You did not take into account the death rate (say 30-40 years average + huge casualties in battles).

Comment: 2. Jews wanted to know if Jesus was the messiah. Jesus responded either cryptically that you are saying it not I or stated that he came from heaven or that he will be seated on the right hand of God etc. The Only thing they were upset about is that Jesus equaled himself to God. So that does not give strength to your hostility theory.

Comment: As for the section of Jesus Claims, just making a claim does not make it real. James and all other offspring of Joseph and Mary are descendants of David. Your point about adoption is not true as the Gospels are keen to make Jesus a divine being without a Father(Matthew+Luke). John believes Geneology is silly as Jesus is God who created the whole world. Paul proves that Jesus only had a mother to fulfill what was prophesied in Genesis 3 that the seed of the woman will destroy the snake aka satan.

Comment: I Will not comment on your Synoptic problem as most scholars confirm that Mark is #1 and Matthew and Luke are the synoptics.

Comment: 1. I agree with the video that there is only one God, 
2. Never believed Jesus is the same God that came down and died for me to save me.
3. Trinity was never an issue as it has been the worst mistake the church made and continues to make things worse.
4. The challenge I am facing now is that none of the New Testament references to the Tanak are true. They are either out of context, changed, or not prophecies.
5. New Testament points of what Jesus fulfilled and will fulfill what the Messiah should accomplish do not align with what God told the prophets in the Tanak.

Comment: @YedduPrasad thanks for the discussion! I have expanded my post to consider the specific concerns you raised. I'm not sure you followed my argument on genealogy--if we assume a lower number instead of 25 years per generation, that would *increase* the exponent and strengthen my argument. I'm not trying to argue for precise census figures, or that Matthew's genealogy is complete--I'm merely pointing out that any way you slice the data, Jesus (and all Jews in His community) were descendants of David.

Comment: Realy appreciate the effort on the math equation. I have never been good at math and so you find it hard to explain math to me. My point is very simple, if there were 12 men(tribes), and all had children and all their children had children, and while these chidren had more children parents died due to age and wars, at any time, you will have children from all the 12 tribes and only some will be from the tribe of David. Not able to get my mind around 1 trillion, 500 mn, 67 mn. The Jews never crossed 20 mn tops during David and solomons rule.

Comment: @YedduPrasad agreed, there certainly were never 1 trillion people on the planet. Rather, people from different tribes intermarried, and so after a number of generations, everyone would have ancestry from every tribe. They'd call themselves members of the tribe through which their patrilineal descent came (father's father's father etc), but in reality they were descendants (on different family lines) of all 12 tribes.

Comment: @YedduPrasad if, for sake of simplistic argument, my parents were cousins, I could draw a family tree showing 8 great-grandparents...but I would see 2 of those great-grandparents show up twice on the tree, once on my mom's line and once on my dad's line. So I would only have 6 distinct great-grandparents. Multiply that out 40 generations and you'll have 1 trillion branches on the tree, but they'll be repeats of the same people over and over again, not 1 trillion distinct people.

Answer (score 0):

I expect others have given some of the texts pertaining to the genealogical record, but the Matthew 1 versus Luke 3 "discrepancy" is rarely properly grasped, much less explained.  As this is critical to properly understanding the subject, this is where I will focus.

As anyone who has studied this question knows, no genealogy seems to be provided for Mary, and the two genealogies for "Joseph" diverge.  Instead of assuming that one is correct and one is incorrect, a proper Biblical scholar must assume that they are both correct when properly interpreted according to the Bible's own explanations.

Let's go back to Genesis.

According to God, when a man and a woman marry, they are "one flesh":

> "Therefore shall a man leave his father and his mother, and shall
> cleave unto his wife: and they shall be one flesh." (Genesis 2:28)

Therefore, the first couple, having "one flesh", are ascribed *one name*: that of the man/husband.

> "This is the book of the generations of Adam. In the day that God
> created man, in the likeness of God made he him; Male and female
> created he them; and blessed them, **and called their name Adam,** in the
> day when they were created."  (Genesis 5:1-2)

It should not surprise us, then, that where the woman's name is not specified separately, the name of her husband stands in place of her own in a genealogical record--in much the same manner as surnames (with mister and missus) are often used today.  When "Adam had a son," it is obvious to the reader that his wife was involved, too.

So it is with "Joseph."  The name "Joseph" includes the man and his wife, by the Biblical standard.  It follows, then, that one of those two genealogies given for Joseph is actually that of his wife, Mary.  BOTH genealogies show descendence from David.  Therefore, Mary, a descendant of David and mother of Jesus, gives to Jesus his Davidic genetic heritage.

Comment: 1. The two becoming one is about the man and woman becoming one in the children they have
2. Mary cannot decide the tribe of Jesus only the father can.

Comment: I believe that your first point applies in a physical sense, yes.  But in the sight of God, the two are also a single "unit" and can properly be addressed with one name.  Regarding your second point, if both Joseph and Mary were descendants of David, what problem do you still have?  In the Mosaic laws, women did sometimes determine the tribe--particularly as related to property ownership when unmarried, etc.

Comment: Please can you point me to the bible reference of Man&Woman is one. Can you point me to the verse where a woman determines the tribe. Hope you are not referring to Zelophehad's daughters. Even if you are which does not help, Mary is married to Joseph already so how does that apply. mary can be a descendent of David but this will not make Jesus a descendent of David.

Comment: See Matthew 19:4-6.  But if your mind is made up, and you're looking for a reason _not_ to believe, you surely will find one.  I would humbly suggest you read Mark 11:22-33 and then read Joshua 24:15.  The rest is up to you.  But wait! one text more, just for you: Luke 22:31-32.

Comment: Not sure why you think I am trying to find reasons to not believe the new testament. I believed it for 48 years, For the last 3 years I have been reading it thoroughly and find it difficult to tie it to Tanak, All I am seeking is the truth. I am actually scared of going to hell as that is the only path I get if I question or not believe the new testament.

God bless you. Will continue by seeking.